# Lane detection noise removal (getting too many unnecessary lines)

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I'm trying to do lane detection, the code is as below, I applied HoughLinesP on canny edge detection's o/p. So the idea is to display only the lines that which are (usually present on the video + more probable to be a lane i.e by picking up the angle). I don't want to use any machine learning algorithms. So please help..

Here are the details :

- Code :

  ```
  import time
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  vid = cv2.VideoCapture('4.mp4')

  while True:

      #cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

      ret, img_color = vid.read()

      if not ret:
          vid = cv2.VideoCapture('5.mp4')
          continue

      num_rows, num_cols = img_color.shape[:2]
      rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((num_cols/2, num_rows/2), 270, 0.56)  #3
      img_rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img_color, rotation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))


      height, width = img_rotated.shape[:2]
      img_resize = cv2.resize(img_rotated,(int(0.8*width), int(0.8*height)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC) #2

      img_clone = img_resize[10:842,530:1000].copy()
      img_roi = img_resize[10+250:842-200,530:1000]


      img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_roi,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #1

      kernel = [  [0,-1,0],   [-1,5,-1],  [0,-1,0]    ]
      kernel = np.array(kernel)
      img_sharp = cv2.filter2D(img_gray,-1,kernel)

      blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_sharp,(5,5),0)

      img_canny = cv2.Canny(blur,130,170, apertureSize = 3)   #4

      lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img_canny, 1, np.pi/180, 60, maxLineGap = 240)
      if lines is not None:
          print(len(lines))
          for line in lines:
              x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
              cv2.line(img_clone, (x1,y1+250), (x2,y2+250), (0,255,0), 2)
              #cv2.line(img_clone, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,255,0), 3)


      cv2.imshow('frame',img_clone)
      cv2.imshow('frame2', img_canny)

      k = cv2.waitKey(35) & 0xFF
      if k==27 :
          break

  vid.release()   
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  ```

[Here's link to videos I'm using](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Pm98ZBIiO6t_xoVCf1Vcn0vVwQSsgtyD)

In 4.mp4 you can see that after running this code, a few seconds later a person comes in and there are so many lines as canny detects so many edges in that region, secondly i've fixated region of image for which i want to be dynamic, the idea is to set the region of image on the basis on more probable lanes. 
Also there's a cluster of lines appearing, i want to shorten it down to more probable line. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get much better results. This is just the nature of your problem. You will now have to go into creating a mathematical model of your lane, and use your hough-lines to correct that model.

E.g. you could track the lane in certain bands of the image using a kalman filter. You then can use the predict step of this filter when you observe line segments that are within the expected angle around your observation band.

Comment: can you elaborate more.. I'm new to opencv

Comment: Not really. Of course I could, but we would talk about a several-page article to write. Which is a bit much. The gist of it is that you are not going to get perfect data with "just" CV algorithms. You are now in the land of object tracking in a noisy environment. That's what you have to explore. ML could maybe help solve the overall problem in one step (if you have good data with curvature classification), but you don't want to use that.